# How to change an existing theme to a responsive bootstrap theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I wonder how to update an existing non-responsive Drupal 7 theme to a responsive bootstrap theme? Any hints for that?

The following steps are required:

- Install bootstrap theme.
- Create a bootstrap subtheme.
- Make sass tools ready to compile scss files.
- Start theming.
- Create a new bootstrap subtheme that looks like the old non-responsive theme.

So how can I create such a new responsive subtheme?

Comment: Please review the (minor I think) edits I applied to your question, trying to address the "put on hold" reasons, without changing too much of your actual question. If you don't like my edits at all, no problem, in that case just perform a rollback to the prior version of it (you can find the link in the revision history, next the each of the versions). If you "can live with my edit", you may want to flag it and request a moderator to consider reopening it (IMO my edited version is no longer opinion based). Good luck!

Comment: While I think it does get rid of the opinionated part of the question, it's still a broad question. There might be a good question here, but it's hard to give a general purpose, Drupal-specific, answer to such a broad question.

Comment: Ditto.  This is still too-broad.  The question actually answers itself; those are the steps.  I am not sure if this can be narrowed down to be appropriate for this site and not be a duplicate of something else we already have answered (and getting SASS working would be OT here).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a responsive site in drupal with bootstrap.then follow steps:

1. Install bootstrap theme.(https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap).
2. Copy the bootstrap_subtheme, Place in theme folder and rename with your subtheme.
   3.Copy and include the css and js of the existing site to the bootstrap_subtheme.
3. See the structure of the existing site and create regions in the new theme according  to requirement and apply the css.
4. Check the section one by one and apply the css according.
5. Like this you can easily convert the non-responsive site to responsive.

**Notes**:

- You will be create a regions in the `tpl.php` , [this Link](http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-create-drupal-7-theme-scratch) will help you.
- In this theming there is no that much different to normal theming . if you install bootstrap then it automatically give you the responsive platform, only one difference you can use the bootstrap class in html structure and also use the bootstrap module. [Follow This](https://www.agencyascend.com/blog/integrating-bootstrap-3-your-drupal-7-website).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53348/discussion-on-answer-by-karuna-best-way-for-changing-existing-theme-to-responsiv).